# Saving django model instance into another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 models that inherit from an abstract model. I am using one for relevant data and the other one for archived data. They have the same fields and methods. I would like to create a post_save signal on model A so an instance will be created in model B whenever a new record is created, so far the options out there are not very elegant:

```
a = A.objects.get(id=1)
b = B()
model_dict = a.__dict__
model_dict.pop('id')
b.__dict__ = model_dict
b.save()
```

is there a better way to achieve this?

Note: These models contain foreign keys, as such, the model_to_dict function under django.forms does not work since it only provides the id of the related object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that iterating over field list is more predictable way:

```
a = A.objects.get(id=1)
data = dict([field.name, getattr(a, field.name) for field in a._meta.fields])
b = B(**data)
b.pk = None
b.save()
```

Note: this doesn't handle ManyToMany relationships.  M2M fields should be copied manually.

Comment: (field.name, getattr(a, field.name) )   add extra parentheses to avoid syntax error

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for any of that. Simply setting the id to None will cause it to save as a new instance.

```
a = A.objects.get(id=1)
a.id = None
a.save()
```

Comment: You did not understand the question. It is modelB that needs to be saved (again).